# How to size a wx panel to fit a wx.Notebook (wxpython)

Tags: wxpython, sizer, wxnotebook

I have a frame with a panel containing a notebook at the top level, with each page containing different panes:

```
panel = wx.Panel(self)
self._panel = panel

# Arrange the various views in a notebook

self._topNoteBook = wx.Notebook(panel)

self._installsView = InstallsViewPane(self._topNoteBook)
self._topNoteBook.AddPage(self._installsView, "Your CM Installations")

self._H2HHViewNoteBook = wx.Notebook(self._topNoteBook)
self._topNoteBook.AddPage(self._H2HHViewNoteBook, "Legacy H2HH View")


# Do stuff to create the contents of installsView and H2HHViewNoteBook ...
# [...]

# Attempt to size the panel/topNoteBook so that
# panel doesn't clip the contained notebook
# Cause layout to happen
sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
self._sizer = sizer
sizer.Add(self._topNoteBook, 1, wx.EXPAND)
panel.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)
```

Each of the sub panes sizes itself properly, however I can't get the main frame/panel to expand to fit the top notebook.  Or - maybe my problem is that I can't get the top notebook to expand to fit it's children: I can't actually tell which is the problem, the effect is the same: the main frame is too small for the child notebooks.

The result is that the child panes look fine, but the overall frame is too small: it has to be manually expanded (which works) to see the whole of the children:

[image]

Help?

Comment: Try replacing the SetSizerAndFit() with SetSizer()

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too clear on what problem you're having but I think what you want to do is call:

```
Frame.SetSize((height, width))
```

Where height and width are integers. You can also try using:

```
 something.GetBestSize()
```

That will return a tuple of integers that best fit the somethings widgets.

Also I try to avoid calling SetSizerAndFit(sizer). I generally call SetSizer(sizer) and Layout() on whatever I'm trying to size. In fact I can't remember the last time I called Fit() because it can screw up layouts if you have multiple panels in a Frame.

Comment: Thanks heaps.  I'll try this out as soon as I can and report back.

Comment: I'm sorry my explanation of the problem was not good.   The hints you (and Mike) have given me provide a workaround (IE don't try to make a best fit :) ), but not a solution yet.  I will try to update the question to be clearer.